# How to use a python virtualenv with sudo?

Tags: python, sudo

I am trying to make a python environment separate from the system one (using virtualenv) in a directory which is not under /home, because I need to use it to build other software that has to be accessible to multiple users. I can create and activate the virtualenv all right, but when I `sudo` some command (for example to make or compile other software), it is the system python that is used (I can tell because of the available modules).

Since on Ubuntu it is not a good thing to use the *root* user, is there a way to tell `sudo` to use a virtualenv? Or maybe this is not the correct approach, and I should make a completely new python installation?

I am using the 64bit version of Ubuntu 12.04 (and python 2.7).

Comment: Does the following work? sudo $(which python) <script>

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The issue is almost certainly that when you run `sudo`, the virtualenv environment variables, aliases, functions, etc aren't being carried over.

The solution would be to explicitly run the virtual environment's Python executable with `sudo`. For example if your virtualenv is ./AwesomeProject, then you could run `sudo ./AwesomeProject/bin/python <script>` to use the script with the virtualenv with root privileges.

Comment: You could also let the first line of your script point to the Python binary in your virtualenv. `#!<virtualenv_dir>/bin/python`.

Comment: Ugh, annoying that this is only solution so far.  On Mac, sudo python uses python from the virtual env.

Comment: @OrangeTux I tried what you suggested and it does not work for me when running the script with `sudo python3 my_script.py`

Comment: @kenkinder @gaefan In my case,  I get `Command not found` when using `sudo ./home/pradan/.virtualenvs/sk/bin/python3 main.py
` where main.py is my script and `sk` is name of my virtual env.

Answer (score 14):

Depending on your particular use-case this may or may not solve your problem, but this wasn't yet mentioned here.  Say, you want to run a Python script that was installed in your virtual environment, and you need to `setuid(0)` it, i.e. you want to run it as superuser. Say, your script is called `myscript.py`, then, you can do it like this:

```
(.venv) $ sudo -E env PATH=$PATH ./myscript.py
```

## Explanation

`(.venv) $` is the shell's prompt, you don't need to type it, it just shows that you are currently using some virtual environment, and you are not a privileged user.

`sudo -E` will tell `sudo` that when starting a process, it needs to copy the environment variables from your current shell environment.  So, if you have any extra variables defined in `.venv/bin/activate` script, they should stick around while you are `root`.

`env PATH=$PATH` when using `sudo -E` not all environment variables are preserved, specifically, and most importantly, the `PATH` may be removed. The specifics of this behavior will depend on your sudoers file.  This, however, will circumvent whatever's written in sudoers file, as it will copy the `PATH` explicitly into environment `sudo` creates for the new process. This is important because when your system resolves shebang comment in your `myscript.py`, it will look in the `PATH` variable, and the first directory to match the requirement for interpreter will be used. `venv` on the other hand, sets up the shell environment in such a way that the directory containing the symlink to the chosen Python interpreter appears first, thus causing system to locate the desired Python before any other Pythons on system path.

Answer (score 4):

Just stumbled across this and for others who may find the same issue, Ken is correct that the env variables are not being carried over.  The solution I used was to add the following lines to my script.  This has the added benefit of always loading the virtual environment directly from the script.  (Meaning you can use the script with crontab or launchd without any other workarounds.)

```
base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
activate_this = os.path.join(base_dir, 'venv/bin/activate_this.py')
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

More background here: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide.html#using-virtualenv-without-bin-python

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes you need the $PATH updated because the script runs other programs. For example pypi-install needs py2dsc-deb in the PATH. This command works: `sudo sh -c ". venv/bin/activate ; pypi-install $PACKAGE"`

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add my answer because I stumbled across the same problem right now. But I created a shell script for a repo, and therefore I didn't want to use a hardcoded path. The following is what I am doing now:

1. Enter your venv:
   `source /path/to/your/venv/bin/activate`
2. Get the path to the python3 binary of the venv without sudo:
   `PYTHON3_VENV_PATH=$(which python3)`
3. Now you can run your script with sudo and the python3 binary:
   `sudo $PYTHON3_VENV_PATH path/to/your/script.py`