# How to install a package in the root directory using virtual environment?

Tags: 14.04, sudo, pip, virtualenv, numpy

I have created a virtual environment in the root directory and trying to install numpy using the command:

```
pip install numpy
```

It gives the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
```

If I use **sudo**,it will be installing system wide,but I already have it installed system wide,so it results in the following statement:

```
Requirement already satisfied
```

Can anyone please provide some suggestion how to install numpy in the virtual environment which is placed in the root directory.

Thanks.

Comment: Please have a look at this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/234758/how-to-use-a-python-virtualenv-with-sudo

Comment: By reading that answer,I used the pip in the virtual environment folder,but that also gives the permission denied error

Comment: Did you activate the virtual environment? It must be done with something like `source path/to/your/environment/bin/activate`. Also I would advise you to use pip3 to use python 3, because there is no valid reason to start with python 2 in 2018.

Comment: yes,I have activated the virtual environment,I was trying to install it with pip3 first,same error,so I thought to use pip.

Comment: @SebastianStark,thanks for the link,that gave the idea to use the appropriate pip,was not using sudo with that earlier, it works,thanks