# Access python os.environ var in virtualenv with sudo?

Tags: command-line, python3, django

I am working on a django project where I have to keep secrete information to python's os.environ.

by following below link 
http://barkas.com/2016/set-environment-variables-activating-virtualenv/
code is working fine in local system.

Now when I run getting secrete key

```
$/home/env/bin/python
>> import os
>> os.environ
environ({'SECRETE_KEY': '000000')
```

but while excuting same command with **sudo** getting different environ variables.

I need to get **environ({'SECRETE_KEY': '000000')** with using **sudo /home/env/bin/python**

Also tried with
[How to use a python virtualenv with sudo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234758/how-to-use-a-python-virtualenv-with-sudo)

but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

BASH Variables are scoped.  This means they are only available to certain things and not shared system-wide.

When you instantiate a variable, it is available for the current shell (`x="apple"`).  When you export, that variable is available in the current shell, and subsequent shells/functions (`export x="apple"`).  If you close that shell/terminal, you lose that variable.

For this reason, common variables are added to user profiles so that they are loaded properly.  This is typically done using `export` in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`.

Similar to how the variable is lost if you close your terminal, these variables are lost if you switch users.

**If you want `root` to have access to a BASH variable, you have to declare the variable within the `root` shell.**  You can duplicate your (assumed) `export`s in your `~/.bashrc` into the `root` user's `/root/.bashrc` file, and have that sourced properly.

You may be able to export/push all variables by looking at `man sudo` (look at `-E`), as I know it has a few options on whether to switch to the new user's directory and possibly share variables, but this isn't the approach I would take.

Instead, similar to how you'd share a web server directory (`/srv/www/`) by having a shared group own the file (`www-data`, `g+rwx`), and making sure only that group can read the file (`o-rwx`), we will create a shared file to source and secure against unauthorized users. So,  you can add the following to each user's `~/.bashrc` file that is in the group and you want to have access to the variable:

```bsh
$ touch /srv/www/.bashrc_shared
$ chown www-data:www-data /srv/www/.bashrc_shared
$ chmod g+rwx /srv/www/.bashrc_shared
$ chmod o-rwx /srv/www/.bashrc_shared
$ vim /srv/www/.bashrc_shared

#!/bin/bash

export MY_SECRET_VAR="super_secret_var"
```

Now, ensure `~/.profile` sources this file, or your `~/.bashrc` which then sources this file, **or** run `sudo` with the `-i` flag:

```bsh
cat ~/.profile 
# ~/.profile
#

[[ -f /srv/www/.bashrc_shared ]] && source /srv/www/.bashrc_shared
```

**OR**

```bsh
sudo -i your_command # Source config files
```