# Using 'sudo' with `virtualenv`

Tags: bash, sudo, python3, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am working on a virtual environment: `sk`, which I made this way:

```
$ mkvirtualenv sk -p python3
```

I use `workon sk` to activate this environment and work in it. When I try to run some functionality of the `perf` utility in it, it asks for permission; it advises me to use `sudo`. On doing so, the essence of the environment gets lost as it doesn't detect any packages that I installed in it (e.g. `pandas`).

I have already gone through the similar article on this site as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234758/how-to-use-a-python-virtualenv-with-sudo/245921#comment2094001_245921), which suggests using the command

```
sudo ./AwesomeProject/bin/python <script>
```

where virtualenv is `./AwesomeProject`. I tried it and found the Python instance within my virtual environments to be as `./.virtualenvs/sk/bin/python3`. I run the instance as:

```
$./.virtualenvs/sk/bin/python3 main.py
```

I get `bash: .virtualenvs/sk/bin/python3: No such file or directory`

*(`main.py` is the python script I intend to run)*

Why do I face this error with sudo and how should I overcome this ?

Comment: `./virtualenvs/sk/bin/python3 main.py` ?

Comment: @B.duGaray I have made the required edits. For context, Its actually the solution suggested by the linked answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.virtualenvs` directory is usually in your home directory.
The output suggests that the python executable cannot be found.

Try running `~/.virtualenvs/sk/bin/python3 main.py`